# Filter for several open Faces datatables

Tags: ajax, jsf, openfaces

I have 3 **openFaces** `<o:datatable />`s in the same view page (overview.xhtml).

- The first displays a list of all music bands
- The 2d displays a list of all songs written by music bands
- The 3d displays a list of all shows given by music bands

I am using `<o:inputTextFilter />` to filter the first datatable using 
the row ID (

```
<h:form>
        <o:datatable value="#{bandBean.items}" var="band" ........<o:inputTextFilter 
        expression="#{band.id}" .../> 
</h:form>

<h:form>    
    <o:datatable value="#{showBean.items}" var="show" ........<o:inputTextFilter 
        expression="#{band.id}" .../> 
</h:form>
    <h:form>
    <o:datatable value="#{songBean.items}" var="song" ........<o:inputTextFilter 
        expression="#{band.id}" .../> 
</h:form>
```

The songs and the shows are child objects of music bands.
What I really need is the ability to filter the 3 datatables using the 
same inputTextFilter or something similar, since the 3 datatables have each a column with the  band ID.

The user will never accept typing the band id three times, first 
tilme for the BAND table, second time for the shows table and the 
third time for the song table, using 3 filters. Instead he wants to type once the band 
ID , and instantly the 3 tables get filtered.

One workaround would be to use three `<o:inputTextFilter />` and set their values using javascript or ajax : while the user types something in a filter, the value being typed is appended immediately to the other filters. I can't figure that workaround. yet it seems to be odd to display 3 filters while the user should use only one.
Any ideas and help will be precious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct support for attaching a filter to several tables, 
however you can simulate this behavior. To so this, you can attach a 
hidden  ("display: none") to each of your tables 
using the "for" attribute, and specify the filtering value for all of 
them programmatically.

Here's a simple code snippet which demonstrate this idea:

```
<o:inputText value="#{MyBean.filterText}"/> 
<o:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{MyBean.filterAllTables}"/> 
<o:inputTextFilter for="table1" expression="#{book.bookTitle}" 
                   value="#{MyBean.filterCriterion}" style="display: none"/> 
<o:inputTextFilter for="table2" expression="#{book.bookTitle}" 
                   value="#{MyBean.filterCriterion}" style="display: none"/> 
<o:dataTable id="table1" ...> 
<o:dataTable id="table2" ...>
```

MyBean.java:

```
private String filterText; // a property w/ getter/setter 
private ExpressionFilterCriterion filterCriterion; // a property w/ getter/setter 

public void filterTables() { 
    String filterText = getFilterText(); 
    SimplePropertyLocatorFactory.SimplePropertyLocator propertyLocator =
                new SimplePropertyLocatorFactory.SimplePropertyLocator("id"); // "id" is a property name by which you'd like to filter
    ExpressionFilterCriterion filterCriterion = new ExpressionFilterCriterion(
                propertyLocator, FilterCondition.CONTAINS, filterText); 
    setFiterCriterion(filterCriterion); 
}
```

Comment: Lol :) OK, I was wondering about the the type of filterCriterion and actually it is ExpressionFilterCriterion and not String! Thanks a lot Dmitry, you rock!